# How to create new attributes for products and make them appear in the form like price M2

Tags: magento2, product

I want to create new attributes from BO and make them appear like price and Sku and Quantity.Thanks in advance

Comment: like price and SKU means it should display in product page?

Comment: no it's optionnal attributes but i want to see them like i see sku and qty in BO when adding product and in the grid